# How to construct $A_{n} \uparrow A$ with $A=[0,x)$

Tags: measure-theory

I'm working on a problem. I'm very sure that my solution works. There is a minor detail which I have not given much attention to. I have assumed that there exists a sequence $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with the following property $A_{n} \uparrow A \Longleftrightarrow A_{1} \subset A_{2} \subset A_{3} \subset \ldots \quad$ and $\quad A=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_{n} = [0,x)$.

But actually I can't figure out how to construct such a sequence. (?)

Comment: $A_n=[0,x-\frac 1 n)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Couldn't I also just pick $A_n=[0,x)$ ?

Comment: Well, I thought $\subset$ meant strictly contained in.

Comment: Alright. In my textbook $\subset$ means $\subseteq$. 
Thanks!